# How to test running threads if they are terminating properly when they all done using JUnit

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I've a server class which listens on a particular port number for the requests made by the clients. And for each client it opens a separate Thread of execution.
But the problem is that server program gets hands every after few days and I had to restart that program again and again.

So, I started writing test cases to check whether the threads are terminating properly after their job done and here's my code

```
public class ExampleTestWithJunit extends TestCase {

public void testExampleThread() throws Throwable {

    int client = 0;
    while(true) {
        Runnable tr1 = new GPSService(new Socket(), client++, "http://localhost/url1");         
        Thread thread = new Thread(tr1);

        System.out.println("State: "+thread.getState());
        System.out.println("Is Alive..? "+thread.isAlive());
        thread.start();         
    }
}

private class GPSService implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    private int clientNumber;
    private String serverUrl;
    public GPSService(Socket socket, int clientNumber, String serverUrl) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
        this.serverUrl = serverUrl;
        System.out.println("New connection with client# " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);            
    }

    public void run() {
       //My Business logic      
    }
}    
}
```

And From Here's I'm not able to figure it out how can check whether all the threads are closing properly.
If I'm wrong any where feel free to point out else please suggest me in achieving this. I've been stuck with this for days and I hope I'll find proper answer in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ExecutorService` with a predefined number of threads and submit your jobs to this `ExecutorService`.

When that is done you can attempt to shut down the executor (no jobs will be halted by this operation). Then you can poll the executor to see whether all jobs are completed yet and act upon that.

Example code:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    int numThreads = 10;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        executor.execute(new GPSService());
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        // Threads are still running
    }
    // All threads are completed
}
```

Comment: @K Erlandsson your answer started making sense to me but a small clarification, you've mentioned predefined number of threads, but I can't do that in my program since its dynamic where threads keep getting fired

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada I'm not sure I understand. In your example code you start the threads from your test. If you want to do that you can't start the threads "dynamically". You could however choose another way to start the threads than to submit 10 at the start of the test, if that is what you want. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @K Erlandsson That's my bad. you've mentioned "You could however choose another way to start the threads than to submit 10 at the start of the test, if that is what you want". And that's what I meant to ask and now I understood. Thank You

Comment: This approach works good though if you want to perform assertions from your workers threads you might look at [ConcurrentUnit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit).